# Formulário sendo enviado duas vezes seguidas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho esse código no meu JS:

`$('#form-sign-in').bind('submit', function(e)`

E no meu `FORM` tem um `Input Type Submit`. Quando clico nele para fazer um simples cadastro, está mandando duas solicitações.

Estou utilizando **ajax**.

Eu vejo no Inspect Element do Google na aba *XHR* e me mostra duas requisições para a página de cadastro.

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseURL + '/form-cadastro',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Aguarde...').prop('disabled');
        },
        success: function(result){
            $('input, label').hide();
            $('.message').html(result).addClass('message');

            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.message').html('').addClass('message');
                $('input, label').show();
                $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Confirmar').removeProp('disabled');
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Troca o tipo do seu botão pra button.

Comment: @Marconi, não era isso apenas. Mas ajudou.

Comment: Que bom ter te ajudado @DiegoSouza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Diego**, provavelmente você está esquecendo de prevenir o padrão ([`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)).

**Problema**

O botão está enviando (por ser do tipo `submit`) e o `bind` está interceptando, duplicando a requisição. É importante que o botão não seja do tipo `submit`, senão ele envia o formulário de verdade e seu ajax também (já que o `form` está com o `bind`).

**Solução**

Para facilitar, ao invés de usar `$('#form-sign-in').bind('submit', function(e)` no escopo, poderia fazer:

1. Troque o tipo de botão de `type="submit"` para `button`.
2. Insira um ID neste botão, exemplo: `<button id="btEnviar">Enviar</button>`
3. Chame o `JQuery` para enviar o form usando este botão:

   ```
   $('#btEnviar').on('click', function()
   {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: baseURL + '/form-cadastro',
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           beforeSend: function(){
               $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Aguarde...').prop('disabled');
           },
           success: function(result){
               $('input, label').hide();
               $('.message').html(result).addClass('message');

               setTimeout(function(){
                   $('.message').html('').addClass('message');
                   $('input, label').show();
                   $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Confirmar').removeProp('disabled');
               }, 4000);
           }
       });

   });
   ```

Comment: Outra coisa poderia ser a troca do tipo do botão pra button.

Comment: Sim, com certeza. O botão está enviando o e `bind` está interceptando, duplicando a requisição.

Comment: Felipe, realmente era isso que estava ocorrendo. Mas além disso também, em uma das páginas estava com um JS duplicado (devido estar trabalhando com blades template), no qual continha esse script. O que o fazia chamar duas vezes a mesma função.

Comment: Nossa, hehe, realmente. Que bom que deu certo

Answer (score 3):

Coloca no seu form `onsubmit="return suaFuncao()"` e no seu botão *submit* `onclick=return suaFuncao()`.

E no seu js:

```
function suaFuncao() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseURL + '/form-cadastro',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Aguarde...').prop('disabled');
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('input, label').hide();
                $('.message').html(result).addClass('message');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.message').html('').addClass('message');
                    $('input, label').show();
                    $("#confirmar-cadastro").val('Confirmar').removeProp('disabled');
                }, 4000);
            }
        });
    return false; /* <-- IMPORTANTE ISSO AQUI pra quebrar o submit */
}
```

Comment: Outra coisa poderia ser a troca do tipo do botão para 'button' em vez do return false.

Comment: @Marconi não resolve totalmente, pois se o usuário der um `enter` dentro do input ele faz um submit no form :)

Comment: Hum não sabia. De qualquer jeito outra boa resposta aqui.

Comment: Exato, apenas o `button` não resolve o problema. É uma boa resposta, mas é que eu não trabalho assim, com funções, visto que uso mais o jQuery para chamar ações pelo elemento.